# How do you decide whether or not to mark event properties as indexed?

Tags: solidity, events

This is from the UniswapV2Factory:

`event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);`

`address pair` could have been marked as indexed since up to three indexed designations are allowed per event.  It's not clear to me why they didn't do that.

My question:  What is a good rule of thumb for deciding when to mark parameters as indexed?

Comment: I believe it's for event subscribing and filtering. Unindexed events cannot be filtered by topic and therefore would need to check the data payload in transaction receipt. It also costs less gas if they aren't indexed

Comment: That is a helpful explanation for an Ethereum node.  I wonder if there is any sense in adding "indexed" when using the Graph, since it filters by a mechanism other than topics.